# iOS 6 auto layout error in multiplier, one pixel lost

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is a little bit weird. I have a control that layouts horizontally an aribitrary number of buttons, like a segmented control. Inside a for loop, for each button, I have this very simple constraint:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                multiplier:1.0f / buttonsCount
                                                  constant:0.0f]];
```

I want all the `button` to has the same width in relation to its superview (`self`). But on iOS 6 (on 7 it is all OK) at the right of the control I get an empty pixel (white, the background of the container of my control) and more strange: all the view that contains my control has that pixel at the right.

I changed that constraint, only to test, to have `multiplier = 1.0f` an `constant = round(320.0f / buttonsCount)` and all works fine (but this is only for test purposes, that 320 is unacceptable).

What is the problem? Can I specify the same constraint in other way?

Comment: You're right, a rounding issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved as @Shadowfiend commented, rounding issues:

```
float buttonWidthMultiplier = roundf((1.0f / buttonsCount) * 100.0f) / 100.0f;
```